# UIPageViewController to display views with different heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

Lets say I have View Controller 1, View Controller 2 and View Controller 3.
Each VC will show some data/metrics.

- VC1 will have a View with height h(h is around 75% screen size),
- VC2 will have a view with height h*3
- and VC3 will have a view with h*4.

I need to scroll between these views with paging enabled.

What is the best way to structure such a requirement ?
Can I use a UIPageViewController to display views of different heights but same widths ?

Comment: Yes, have you tried?